# No warning or error when using (unsupported) event handler inside DataTemplate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, silverlight, events

### Scenario

Consider the following XAML inside a view of a **Silverlight** application:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" MouseLeftButtonDown="Item_Clicked" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The event handler is not called. Apparently, event handlers do not work inside `DataTemplate`.

There are no warnings or errors, neither at compile-time nor at runtime. Also, the [MSDN DataTemplate reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) does not specify any restrictions regarding event handlers.

IntelliSense even "helps" me with `<New Event Handler>` and `Navigate to Event Handler`. The handler is placed in the code behind of the view.

### Questions

1. Is the behavior specified by Microsoft?
2. Is it a known bug in VS2010?
3. Why doesn't the compiler emit an error or
   at least a warning?

### Remark

I know how to solve the issue since the problem is reported quite often on this site. I want to know why this fails silently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Silent error" never gets you very far when your write .NET code, errors are never silent.  I'll describe a general way you tackle issues like this, getting you to the "why" automatically and giving you a chance to google a solution.

An important implementation detail you need to know is how XAML is processed when your app is built.  It is interpreted by a code generator, it auto-generates C# code which is stored in the `obj\Debug` directory of your project.  After you build, you'll find `*.g.cs` files there.  Take a look at them, you shouldn't have too much trouble making sense of them, the code that was auto-generated from the markup is annotated with `#line` directives.

Looking at the Silverlight version, MainPage.g.cs, shows little code (edited to fit):

```
   public partial class MainPage : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl {
       internal System.Windows.Controls.Grid LayoutRoot;
       private bool _contentLoaded;

       public void InitializeComponent() {
          // etc..
       }
   }
```

No sign of the MouseLeftButtonDown event anywhere, this is not encouraging of course.

Do the exact same thing with a sample WPF app.  Now take a look at MainWindow.g.cs (again edited to fit and remove the boring parts):

```
   public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window,
                      System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector, 
                      System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector {
       private bool _contentLoaded;

       public void InitializeComponent() {
           //...
       }

       void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
           //...
       }

       void System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
           switch (connectionId)
           {
           case 1:

           #line 9 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
           ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)(target)).MouseLeftButtonDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(this.Item_Clicked);
           //...
           break;
           }
       }
```

Big difference, now you **do** see the MouseLeftButtonDown event back.  Clearly the `IStyleConnector` interface is instrumental to get that event subscribed.

So go have a look at the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.istyleconnector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that interface.  It is rather brief, this is internal plumbing that you shouldn't have to know about, description is:

> Provides methods used internally by the WPF XAML parser to attach events and event setters in compiled XAML.

A complete match for what you are trying to accomplish of course.  Most important in that article is the Version Information section.  Supported in the .NET Framework, but Silverlight is **not** listed.

This gives you the "why", the necessary plumbing is simply not available in Silverlight.  Otherwise not surprising, the most important attribute of Silverlight is that it is *small*, allowing for a quick download that doesn't slow down the user too much when he browses to a web page that uses it.  It can only get small by removing stuff.

So, apparently you are supposed to provide that plumbing yourself.  How do you do this?  The inspired google query is [silverlight datatemplate event](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=silverlight+datatemplate+event).  The very first hit is a winner, [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684986/is-it-possible-to-bind-an-event-in-a-silverlight-datatemplate) that tries to do *exactly* what you are doing.  Lots more relevant hits available if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and for your tips on how to research such an issue. Your explanation makes total sense from a Framework point-of-view. I would still expect a warning at run-time when some of the XAML is not supported by the framework.

Comment: Agreed, but couldn't a warning be emitted at build time?

Comment: Anything is possible, nothing is automatic until Microsoft takes care of it.  Best place to ask [is here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. It was very helpful an enlightening.